# Swing Worker Usage in mixed threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jprogressbar

I have a GUI which consists of a toolbar with each button invoking different classes. The class I invoke consist of UI components which are displayed in the Internal frame of the main GUI. The Invoked class works as a separate thread and has to perform the following functions.

1. Trigger a command to the client, so that the client starts sending
   the contents of a file.
2. Receive the file contents here,filter it and add it to a JTable.
3. Progress bar has to be displayed during the file contents transfer.
4. Display the UI after adding it to the table.

I am new to Swing worker, so can some one help me to get how it works with my situation and the advantages of using Swing Worker and Invoke later function. I followed the examples in the oracle site and few other sites but I am not able to see how this works for my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwingWorker` has...

- Progress change functionality built in, via the `PropertyChange` support
- Has helper methods that allow you to synchronise updates to the UI via the `publish` and `process` methods, making the process significantly easier...
- A self contained workflow concept which makes it (generally) easier to use than rolling your own.  There are exceptions to the rule, but your outline doesn't fit those exceptions (IMHO) - this is both and advantage and disadvantage...

For example...

- [java swingworker thread to update main Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937997/java-swingworker-thread-to-update-main-gui/16938228#16938228)
- [JProgressBar won't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094666/jprogressbar-wont-update/13095992#13095992)
- [Populating jTable using database data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124904/populating-jtable-using-database-data/15125161#15125161) (relates to updating a `JTable` from a SQL source, but shows how a `SwingWorker` might be used to update a `JTable`)

One of the (possible) drawbacks to `SwingWorker` is it will only allow (I believe) 10 workers to be executed simultanously

Comment: The worker thread limit applies when you invoke `execute()` on a `SwingWorker` which will use an internal `ExecutorService`. However, you can `submit` the `SwingWorker` to an arbitrary `ExecutorService` not having such a limit, alternatively. This possibility is documented, hence not just a side-effect.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your reply. I saw your replies. My problem is, I don't get any mistakes while updating the table. It works fine but when I run progress bar as a separate frame, it isn't shown. Only the frame outline is shown that too is in opaque state. Its like of some kind of glass pane that appears instead of the frame.

Comment: @Holger I haven't used executor service upto now, so I not able to get your point. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Holger Agreed, that could be filled out a bit more, knowing that you can only `execute` 10 `SwingWorker`s in this fashion is sometimes important

Comment: @Parthe I'd need to be able to see more details about the frame.  Sounds like something is blocking it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Currently my class structure is like send trigger to client in constructor,create UI in one function and then receive contents and update table and then show UI with another function. Is this OK or do I need to improve upon my coding structure.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The main UI is a frame with toolbar and desktop pane to  display internal frame. The components of the Internal frame for different classes are a table and 2 buttons. Kind of like a log report.

Comment: It depends, you're loading the data via the `SwingWorker`, then you should be able to use the `SwingWorker`'s in built progress functionality to provide feedback to the UI in order to update it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I haven't used swing worker and invoke later. I am thinking of using it so wanted some suggestions. If I intend to use it, I have to change nearly 3000 lines of code to the format.

Comment: `SwingWorker` generally is easier to use the `invokeLater` - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer The main GUI class wasn't framed by me. I framed only few sub classes and connected it with them. Now if I have to change it, I have to get permission and correct the code. It seems like I have to rebuild the code. So what I did is that I created a progress bar class in which progress bar is in Indeterminate mode. Where ever I need I initiated the class and showed and disposed the frame. As a result of this, the glass pane I told about occurs.

Comment: Have tried just displaying the progress bar frame in isolation to make sure it's working...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I actually designed the progress bar as a separate class and then I added it to my app. I am sure it runs.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So how do I solve that? Make the progress bar a separate thread?

Comment: No.  The UI must only be interacted with from the context of the EDT. Use the `SwingWorker`, in the `doInBackground` method do your long running operations, if you know how much work you have to do, you can use `setProgress` to trigger a `PropertyChange` event which your progress window can display...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I get it now. I invoke UI components using invokeLater,do my Process in background which updates the progress bar. I can use done method to perform operations that I want to do after the completion of my long running process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just call `setProgress` and use a `PropertyChangeListener` to update the progress bar?