# Proplem with swingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

i am using a loading dialog to be visible when i go to dB and searches for the data so i am using swing worker to be able to view the loading dialog while searching for the data

what happen is it couple of time then it raises exp and another couple of time then app goes invisible

my code:

```
  public void unansweredAdminMsgViewGetData(UnAnsweredAdminFrame frame) {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> w = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (!me.isVisible()) {
                Thread.sleep(100); //wait for the dialog to be visible
            }

            frame.getData(); //searches and sets the data to the taple
            me.setVisible(false);
            return null;
        }
    };

    w.run();

    me.setVisible(true);  //view the loading dialog
  }
```

so i have the following exp :

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5720)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:744)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:744)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1532)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1455)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:306)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1252)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5165)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4976)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:811)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1656)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1608)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at archive.dialogs.LoadingDialog.unansweredAdminMsgViewGetData(LoadingDialog.java:269)
at archive.frames.UnAnsweredAdminFrame.setTableData(UnAnsweredAdminFrame.java:473)
at archive.frames.UnAnsweredAdminFrame.answeredRadioButtonItemStateChanged(UnAnsweredAdminFrame.java:354)
at archive.frames.UnAnsweredAdminFrame.access$300(UnAnsweredAdminFrame.java:33)
at archive.frames.UnAnsweredAdminFrame$6.itemStateChanged(UnAnsweredAdminFrame.java:203)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireItemStateChanged(AbstractButton.java:2050)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.itemStateChanged(AbstractButton.java:2353)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireItemStateChanged(DefaultButtonModel.java:455)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setSelected(JToggleButton.java:272)
at javax.swing.ButtonGroup.setSelected(ButtonGroup.java:165)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setSelected(JToggleButton.java:254)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:289)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

after that it works for couple of time then app goes invisible

Comment: What does the `getData` method do?  You do realise that Swing is not thread safe and that you should never modify the UI in any way from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread?

Comment: i know but i need to make a loading dialog that performs external DB action and updates the view

Comment: So, the dialog should opened and closed within the EDT, all updates to the UI should be done within the EDT, that's what the publish method is for. For some reason, the table is been updated out Sid elf the EDT, there is your problem...

Comment: ok i understand that swing not thread safe and i need to update the view where waiting indicator is shown and running while the updating is done in background what should i do??!!

Comment: You need to move what ever code is updating the UI back to EDT, using the publish/process methods of the SwingWorker if possible

Comment: could you give ex for that thanks a lot for your help

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414109/populate-jtable-with-large-number-of-rows/17415635#17415635) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124904/populating-jtable-using-database-data/15125161#15125161)