# Radio buttons generation and data submission through jtables

Tags: java, jquery, swing

I want help to make a pure java project for attendance system . And I want to fetch data from database and generate radio buttons across each row/student and in the last submit the attendance through those radio buttons. Here I have an image from where I had this idea. Kindly help me as it is very important for me.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lwDP.png]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15125161/925792

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to add JRadioButton to group in JTable*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11176480/230513).