# JTextArea refreshment while SQL query running using java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

I have a TextArea Object, and I have SQL query running, I have the GUI unusable until the SQL query is finished, I would like to get the GUI refreshed meanwhile.

Comment: Please provide your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), So that we can help you on where to resolve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Populating jTable using database data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124904/populating-jtable-using-database-data/15125161#15125161) - I know, you have a `JTextArea`, the answer has a `JTable`, but the mechanism used to populate the `JTable` is what you should be using to keep the UI responsive

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is running on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which is preventing the GUI from updating itself until the long running task is finished.

You need to run the query on a separate `Thread`.

An easy way to do this is to use a `Swing Worker`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the `EDT` and for examples of using a `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score -1):

private String printCommandCalled(String argument) throws SQLException {
        String finalResult = "";
        url = url.substring(0, 15 + port.length() + adress.length()).concat(currentDatabaseName + "?useSSL=false");
        try {
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + argument + ";");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        int i = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

```
    //this is the try block that takes too long resulting the unresponsiveness of the gui
    try {

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                finalResult += resultSet.getObject(j) + "      ";
            finalResult += '\n';
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        finalResult += resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(k) + " ("
                + resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(k) + ")      ";
    finalResult += '\n';

    //this output is a string that will be shown in the JTextArea object
    return finalResult;
}
```